# Read a crossword

Tags: code-golf, string, crossword

Inspired by [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74970/stuffing-primes-in-a-box) about packing into this format.

Occasionally I see a completed crossword and being as I am, I can't be bothered to find out what the solutions to the clues actually were.

### Input:

- A 2D string (any format, newline separated, 2d list etc.)
- Blank squares will be represented with a  (space character)
- Every other square will be in the lower case alphabet.
- You may assume that the input will be padded with spaces to form a rectangle

### Output:

- Each word found

  - You must search for words along and down
  - Words will be at least two letters long
  - If there are duplicate words, you have to output them for each time they appear
- You don't have to do any validation
- Words may be outputted in any order
- No strict formatting rules

### Test cases:

```
word
e e 
step
t d 

word, step, west, reed
---
pies
 not
  no
wasp

pies, not, no, wasp, in, eons, stop
---
igloo
    n
word

igloo, word, on
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

*saved one bytes thanks to @issacg.*

```
t#cjsCB
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%23cjsCB&input=%22pies%22%2C+%22+not%22%2C+%22++no%22%2C+%22wasp%22&debug=0).

```
t#               Filter by if len > 1
 c               Chop by whitespace by default
  j              Join by newlines
   sCB           Input, implicit and its transpose in one list
```

Comment: @Maltysen Wonderful.

Comment: Pyth wins. As always.

Comment: You can save one byte by removing the `d`, which makes `j` join on newlines, which are still chopped by `c ... )`

Comment: @isaacg that's really cool, thanks

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 14 bytes

```
{_z+S*S%{,(},}
```

An unnamed block that expects a list of (padded) strings on top of the stack and leaves a list of words instead.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B%22pies%22%0A%20%22%20not%22%0A%20%22%20%20no%22%0A%20%22wasp%22%5D%0A%0A%7B_z%2BS*S%25%7B%2C(%7D%2C%7D%0A%0A~p)

#### Explanation

```
_z    e# Duplicate and transpose the grid.
+     e# Append the transpose to the original grid.
S*    e# Join all lines by spaces to ensure that we don't get words 
      e# spanning multiple lines.
S%    e# Split around spaces, discarding empty segments.
{,(}, e# Filter: keep only those strings with length 2 or greater.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ø«€#J˜ʒ¦Ā
```

Input as a character matrix.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I5Dqx81rVH2Oj3n1KRDy440/P8fHa1UoKSjlAnEqUBcrBSrE62kAGTlAXE@EJfARRCiIJFyICsRrEMHaEJsLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU@l1aLcOl5J/aQlEwL7S5f/hHYdWP2pao@x1es6pSYeWHWn4X6vzPzo6WqlcSUcpH4iLgDhFKVYnWikVyAKaAqVBIsVAVglUpAAsUgJVkwJRE6ujADSqAMjJhCorBisDKcmDWlACF0GIgkRADkgE6wAbDjEKZEw6EOdANeejaEYYAjMA4QOIe2IB).

**Explanation:**

```python
ø          # Zip/transpose the (implicit) input-matrix; swapping rows/columns
 «         # Merge this list of lists to the (implicit) input list of lists
  €        # For each inner list:
   #       #  Split them on spaces
    J      # Join each innermost list together to a single string
     ˜     # Flatten the entire list
      ʒ    # Filter the strings by:
       ¦   #  Remove the first character of the string (no-op if it's already empty)
        Ā  #  And check that it's non-empty
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Typo in title ?

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

```
s=>(s+` `+[...(t=s.split`
`)[0]].map((_,i)=>t.map(t=>t[i]).join``)).match(/\w\w+/g)
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 322 bytes

I can't prove that this works, but feel free to test it in Microsoft SQL server Management Studio sql server 2017+

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)=
('MICROWAVE
U       S
M OCEAN C
M  OWL  A
I SWELL P
E       E
SCHEDULES');

WITH C as(SELECT 1x,@ a UNION ALL SELECT 
iif(ascii(a)=13,0,x+1),stuff(a,1,1,'')FROM C
WHERE''<a)SELECT w FROM(SELECT(SELECT left(a,1)FROM
c WHERE x=t.x for xml path(''),type).value('.','char(99)')a
FROM c t GROUP BY x UNION ALL SELECT @)r
CROSS APPLY(SELECT*FROM string_split(translate(a,'
','  '),' '))g(w)WHERE len(w)>1
```

This script will return

```
MUMMIES
COW
EWE
ALL
ESCAPES
MICROWAVE
OCEAN
OWL
SWELL
SCHEDULES
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
[:(#~1<#&>)@,' '<;._1"1@,.],|:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY6xisJAEIb7eYofBddAXIzlqkfuBKvjClsJImbUHCEb3IU04qvHGcXCxmKGYff/vpn/fmDNEUsHgxRTOKmJxWrzu@63bjy8ZYvh6CvJUwOzmNtdNsjy1Bbp1fUJfQ4Q8eHscUQhzzMUap9S5y8lMRgUIrcUUYISor8fi@@6RuQQcdgHDkQ6Ly3Ukk8ctu7lIhrPnVETVIJOoQtzaZKn4NMmRduKAxofpdDtQ4uqAfsmiM63bxJNkkYJ0knDL0l1qr3geoVv3qDHjwCCPK6Qvf0d)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 9 bytes

```
,+Fdc#t(s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2C%2BFdc%23t%28s&input=%5B%22word%22%2C%22e+e+%22%2C%22step%22%2C%22t+d+%22%5D)

Or 7 bytes prettified

```
,+Fdc#t
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2C%2BFdc%23t&input=%5B%22word%22%2C%22e+e+%22%2C%22step%22%2C%22t+d+%22%5D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
Lm:d"\S\S+"1byQyCQ
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lm%3Ad%22%5CS%5CS%2B%221byQyCQ&input=%5B%22pies%22%2C%22+not%22%2C%22++no%22%2C%22wasp%22%2C%22+t++%22%5D&debug=0)

Sample input:

```
["pies"," not","  no","wasp"," t  "]
```

Sample output:

```
[['pies'], ['not'], ['no'], ['wasp'], []]
[[], ['in', 'at'], ['eons'], ['stop']]
```

How it works:

```
Lm:d"\S\S+"1byQyCQ                                 The "1" here is mode
                    assign('Q',eval_input())       "1" which means show
                    @memoized                      all matches
L                   def y(b):                               v
 m:d"\S\S+"1b           return map(lambda d:regex(d,"\S\S+",1),b)
             yQ     imp_print(y(Q))
               yCQ  imp_print(y(transpose(Q)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 58 bytes

```
import Data.List
f x=[w|w@(_:_:_)<-words=<<x++transpose x]
```

Usage example: `f ["pies"," not","  no","wasp"]` -> `["pies", "not", "no", "wasp", "in", "eons", "stop"]`.

How it works: split each of the lines of the input and the transposition of it at spaces it into a single list words. Keep those that match `(_:_:_)`, i.e. have at least two letters.

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, <s>209</s><s>207</s>201 bytes

Ridiculously high amount of bytes... but oh well. Transpose matrix, split string. Easy. Too bad no native function for transposing

```
[](vector<string>; m){auto t=m;int C=size(m[0]),j=0;for(;++j<C*C;)t[j%C][j/C]=m[j/C][j%C];for(j=0;++j<C+C;){stringstream Z(j<C?m[j]:t[j-C]);string s;while(getline(Z,s,' '))cout<<(size(s)>1?s+' ':"");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using S=vector<string>;
[](S m){
  S t=m;
  int C=size(m[0]),j=0;
  for(;j<C*C;++j)t[j%C][j/C]=m[j/C][j%C]; // Transpose
  for(j=0;j<C+C;++j){ // since rectangle matrix, we can iterate like so
    stringstream Z(j<C?m[j]:t[j-C]); // Get string from m or t
    string s;
    while(getline(Z,s,' '))
      cout<<(size(s)>1?s+' ':"");
  }
}
```

How to use it (note you must enforce padding as the question states):

```
using S = vector<string>;[](S m) { ... }({"pies", " not", "  no", "wasp"});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of lines.

```
cUy)c¸fÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cVI&code=Y1V5KWO4ZsU&input=WwoKIndvcmQKZSBlIApzdGVwCnQgZCIKCiJwaWVzCiBub3QKICBubwp3YXNwIgoKImlnbG9vCiAgICBuCndvcmQiCgpdLW1S) (includes all test cases)

If we could include a leading and/or trailing newline in the input then this could be 7 bytes, taking input as a multi-line string.

```
pÕ·c¸fÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cNW3Y7hmxQ&input=WwoKIgp3b3JkCmUgZSAKc3RlcAp0IGQiCgoicGllcwogbm90CiAgbm8Kd2FzcAoiCgoiCmlnbG9vCiAgICBuCndvcmQKIgoKXS1tUg)

```
cUy)c¸fÅ     :Implicit input of array U
c            :Concatenate
 Uy          :  U transposed
   )         :End concat
    c        :Flat map
     ¸       :  Split on spaces
      f      :Filter elements that return true after
       Å     :  Slicing off the first character, resulting in the (falsey) empty string when length is <2
```

```
pÕ·c¸fÅ       :Implicit input of multi-line string
p             :Append
 Õ            :  The transposition
  ·           :Split on newlines
   c¸fÅ       :As above
```