# Read a crossword with a twist!

Tags: string, fastest-code, crossword

Similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76966/read-a-crossword), but this is a crossword variation!

Instead of only one letter per grid square, you can have *one **or** two*.

## Input:

- A 2d array, or whatever works in your language.
- You can assume valid inputs
- Any array size must work

## Output:

- An array of all the words

  - Across and down
  - All words must be joined together, i.e. linked in an unbroken chain of words (if not return false)
  - Words must be at least two *grid squares*, not letters

#### Example:

```
[["",  "wo", "r",  "k"],
[ "",   "r",  "",   ""],
[ "he", "l",  "lo", ""],
[ "",   "d",  "ad", ""]]
```

#### Returns:

```
["work", "world", "hello", "load", "dad"]
```

#### Example:

```
[["he", "ll", "o"],
[ "",   "",   ""],
[ "wo", "r",  "ld"]]
```

#### Returns:

```
false
```

This is [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code), so I'll be running this on windows 7 with 2.5ghz and 16gb of ram. If your code is really esoteric, provide a link to the compiler so I can actually run it.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You should replace the *two spaces* part with *two grid squares*.

Comment: What size input size will the speed be measured with?

Comment: @MartinEnder the examples

Comment: @epicbob57 That seems way to small to measure reliable timings. You'd mostly be measuring I/O and other overhead.

Comment: @MartinEnder All right, I'll work out a better example for testing

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

```
import numpy
from scipy.ndimage import measurements

def crosswords(arr):
    M=numpy.asarray(arr)
    # check connectivity
    if measurements.label(numpy.where(M!='',1,0))[-1] != 1:
        return 'false'

    words = []
    def get_words(mat):
        for r in mat:
            word,counter='',0
            for c in r:
                if c=='':
                    if counter>1:
                        words.append(word)
                    word, counter = '', 0
                else:
                    word, counter = word+c, counter+1
            if counter > 1:
                words.append(word)
    get_words(M)
    # transpose M
    get_words(M.T)
    return words
```

## Usage:

Function takes an array of array of strings as input:

`crosswords(
[["",  "wo", "r",  "k"],
[ "",   "r",  "",   ""],
[ "he", "l",  "lo", ""],
[ "",   "d",  "ad", ""]])`

Returns the string `false` when connectivity returns multiple labels.
Returns array of valid words otherwise.

I timed it with `timeit`, `time.time()` and using the console command `time` and but I don't know which one to use or which one to post here.

Comment: I realized that I don't have Python 3... anyway, I'll be testing it using time.time()

Comment: I can't seem to install scipy using pip...

Comment: did you use pip3 ?

Comment: pip 9.0.1 (python 3.5)

Comment: oh you are on windows, try it with admin priviliges

Comment: [I had to get help here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip/39945973#39945973)

Comment: Result: 0.002000093460083008

Comment: Problem: `crosswords([['','',''],['','',''],['','','a']])` returns []